# how to define a delay between each mocha retry

Tags: mocha.js

I'm looking for a way that I can apply a little delay between each retires in mocha. I used the option "--retires", but it is getting executed without any delay. Is there any way that I can implement a delay between each mocha retry?

I tried using setTimeout() with a delay along the retries at test level. But I'm looking for something I can use globally, because I have more than 1000 tests in this suite

Im using mocha 8.1

Also is there any way that I can add a hook that runs on all my tests (*it(test name)*) and for all the test files

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Mocha configuration file.

At the project root, create the .mocharc.js file with your retry definitions.

```js
module.exports = {
  diff: true,
  extension: ['js'],
  package: './package.json',
  reporter: 'spec',
  slow: 75,
  timeout: 15000,
  retries: 20,
  ui: 'bdd'
};
```